# unittesting fails on ModuleNotFound in the file to be tested imports

Tags: python

I am writing a small unittest for my method move(). The application is running but when I do python -m unittest app.test.test_move_items, it fails with the following error:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_move
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/daniel/app/test/test_move.py", line 13, in <module>
    from app.move_items import move
  File "/Users/daniel/apps/app/move.py", line 29, in <module>
    from helpers.calculator import determine_move_amount
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

If i do python app/move.py, the output is correct.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
  app
    helpers
      |-calculator.py
    move_items.py
    test
      |-test_move_items.py
```

move_items.py

```
from helpers.calculator import determine_move_amount

def move(list_of_items, move_by):
  pass
```

There is **init**.py file in app and the test directory as well.

Comment: You probably need to do a `from app.helpers.calculator import determine_move_amount`, as your top level namespace is called `app` based on what we can infer from the error message (as `app.move_items` could be imported, it follows that `app.helpers` could also be imported, along with everything underneath there).

Comment: Can you add the imports from calculator.py? It looks like you are trying to import helpers there which cannot be found.

Comment: Alternatively, you are trying to do a [relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=1).  In any case, you also don't appear to have a proper package set up for your project, which makes juggling imports rather difficult.  You may wish to [package your project](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) so you will have proper package names that may then be imported correctly anywhere within the environment.

Comment: @metatoaster for your first input, yes doing app. import works for test but it fails on 'app' module not found when I run the code. Let me see the packaging solution.

Comment: Try taking the `test_move_items.py` file out of the `test` folder.

Comment: @alexpdev i already tried but thanks. Time to give it up.

Comment: @Erick do you have an __init__.py  both in your test directory and in your app directory?